# How to have a select_tag with an "selected disabled hidden" option?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-select, erb, hidden

I want to have a select_tag that includes a field which displays "Please select" to the user.
This field must not be selectable by the user.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I want to have : http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/pm7cefvg/1/

In Rails, I tried to do this :

```
  <%= select_tag(:userchief, options_for_select(@options_for_selectUsers, {:selected => "x1", :disabled => "x1", :hidden => "x1"})) %>
```

(`@options_for_user` is an array which contains multiple key/value elements)
But when I check the source code of my page, I can see this for my option :

```
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="x1">Select</option>
```

That is not what I want to have, the x1 select option appears in the dropdown menu of the select because the hidden field is not present.

How can I do to obtain the same result as I can see in the jsfiddle link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :prompt => "Placeholder" if you want the placeholder to show up only when the attribute is nil at the time the form is rendered. It will be selected by default, but nothing will be saved if user submits. If the attribute is already populated [possibly because a) there's a default value or b) it's an edit form], the placeholder item will be omitted from the list entirely.

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select something"
# => <select id="people" name="people"><option value="">Select something</option><option value="1">David</option></select>
```

OR

Use :include_blank => "Placeholder" if you want to include the placeholder in the rendered list at all times.

## Update

Following code will disable the prompt after change. this is much similar to your example.

```
<%=  select_tag(name = 'person', options_for_select(User.all.unshift("your prompt message"), selected: prompt, disabled: prompt,) ) %>
```

And if you want to remove the prompt on select changes than you need to use jquery.

```
$("#selectBox").change(function(){
   $("#selectBox option[value='']").remove();
}​);
```

Comment: source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557701/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-a-default-placeholder-thing-in-a-select-tag

Comment: It doesn't works at all, I already have tried it, and in your answer you use an other form of select.

Comment: I have updated select_tag of my answer, which contain the prompt option and its conversion to html. hope this will help!

Comment: @testaabalez, please try the updated select_tag. this is much similar to the jsfiddle that you provided. it only not hide the prompt but it disable it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is it possible to disable the prompt from the dropdown list when the user clicks on the select ?

Comment: yes, the updated select_tag is disabling the prompt option. did you try that?

Comment: Yes but sorry, it's a mistake, I wanted to say : to hidden the prompt from the dropdown list when the user clicks on the select ?

Comment: I think you can achieve this by the jquery, I have add the jquery code which you can use for hiding the prompt option from select tag.

Comment: Yes ! I wanted to do it only by using erb, but yes with Jquery it's also a good way to do it, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This is old but just found out a nice way to do this without js. To be sure, this is based on the accepted answer, so credit to the author. Basically adding `display:none` to the selected option will hide it from the options list but will still display in the dropdown initially.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

HTML:

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select([['New', 0, {class: 'hidden'}], ['Improved', 1], ['Fixed', 2]], selected: 0, disabled: 0) %>
```