# "Undefined" placeholder on f.select in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have a form

```
<%= form_for @user, url: contact_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.select(:email, User.all.map(&:email), {}, { class: 'my-form' }) %>
<% end %>
```

which works well but has placeholder "Undefined" in start position.
I tried to get rid of that with

```
<%= form.select(:email, User.all.map(&:email), {placeholder: "Select email"}, { class: 'my-form' }) %>
```

or

```
<%= form.select(:email, User.all.map(&:email), {prompt: "Select email"}, { class: 'my-form' }) %>
```

but still same. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your syntax error the problem? Here is the same line with the quote added" `{placeholder: "Select email"}, { class: 'my-form' })` or was that just a mistake when you were posting it here? Also, what Ruby + Rails version are you using? Also, have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557701/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-a-default-placeholder-thing-in-a-select-tag

Comment: I made a mistake when I was posting here. I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.1. Yes, I saw and tried it but still same thing(although it's for select_tag).

Comment: Are you using `select` or `select_tag`?

Comment: I'm using `select`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form.select :email, options_for_select(User.all.map(&:email)), include_blank: "whatever your prompt says" , class: 'my-form' %>
```

Comment: What do you have inside in selector, do you have blank field, do you have User email inside in selector?

Comment: I get just "we're sorry but something went wrong". That "undefied" is just placeholder, it's not clickable...if I click on some of emails in list I can't go back on that "undefined"

Comment: Do you run your app in production env? Do you have access to your logs, can you please send me a few last logs, looks like there some error with the app?

Comment: Oh I had a typo there...Now class won't work while placeholder works

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same issues today and this is what I did for one of our projects recently.

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(Category.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }), { include_blank: 'Select category' }, { class: 'custom-select' } %>
```

Try changing the values according to your values.

This is how you add class and placeholder in a form.select element in Rails.