# Placeholder in form_for select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for

The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696834/5783745) to [how do I use a default placeholder ... in a select_tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4557701/5783745) show how to set a *default* value for the select field.

For example:
[image]

[image]

```
<%= f.select :country, countries, {include_blank: true, prompt: "United States"}, {required: true, class: "form-control"} %>
```

The problem here is that I only want the silhouette of the placeholder, not an actual value that could accidentally be submitted.

If we compare to the `placeholder` value in a `text_field`, the difference is much more clear. We ***see*** the placeholder:

[image]

But we cannot accidentally ***submit*** the placeholder.

How can I get similar behaviour with the `.select` field?

That is, so that there *is* some placeholder in the select field, but so it cannot be accidentally submitted?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the *boolean* value of `include_blank: true` to the desired placeholder *string*:

```
<%= f.select :country,
             countries,
             { include_blank: "- nothing selected -" },
             { required: true, class: "form-control" } 
%>
```

This will create a pre-selected select option with no value, which will be interpreted by Rails controllers as `nil`.

Comment: Thank you! I was brain-farting on this and could not find it ... this should be the accepted answer FWIW

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select a `select` has no `placeholder` option. If you wish to show a predefined value that should not be submitted you can add a `disabled` option to this specific item and combine it with `selected`.

```
<%= f.select :country, [['USA', 1], ['Canada', 2]], { disabled: '1', selected: '1' } %>
```