# I am using a form select in ruby on rails. How do I get the blank default to show prompt message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

= f.select :from_id, decorated_froms.map { |from| [from.name, from.id] }, include_blank: "Please select a role to send a message."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placeholder in form\_for select field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332934/placeholder-in-form-for-select-field)

Answer (score 1):

`include_blank`

```
<%= f.select :from_id, decorated_froms.map { |from| [from.name, from.id] }, include_blank: 'Please select a role to send a message.') %>
```

This will always include a blank option in the select, which will allow people to set the value back to the blank value if they're seeing this on an edit form.

`prompt` which is the better option

```
<%= f.select :from_id, decorated_froms.map { |from| [from.name, from.id] }, prompt: 'Please select a role to send a message.') %>
```

This will include the specified prompt value, so long as the field hasn't already been set. If it has (on an edit form for example), there's no need to remind the user that they need to select a value so the prompt doesn't appear.

More on `#select` https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dan!  Unfortunately, the way this select is being used (to generate a "from field" for a message in our app) does not show the prompt, instead the default "from" possibilities for a user are shown. (Seems I am forced to use the :include_blank option.)  The select then defaults to the first "from" option, rather than the desired prompt.  I will now see if I can inject the desired prompt message into the array that is mapped to the dropdown options?  Not a great solution, but still a solution.

Comment: I'd advise `pluck(:name, :id)` instead of `map { |from| [from.name, from.id] }` whenever it applies.